# I cannot range numbers or use this {} in gedit

Tags: command-line, server, gedit

I tried using the syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash

for I in {1..5)
do
    echo $I
done
```

but instead of listing the numbers from 1 to 5, the output is {1..5}
please help me

Comment: `{1..5)` should be `{1..5}`. (curly closing bracket)., but then I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'`

Comment: It looks like you have made a typo in writing your question, since as pLumo pointed out the code you wrote gives a syntax error, and there is no way I can think of you can have put `for I in {1..5)` and got `{1..5}` as output. Please check this. Also, please tell us *how* you are running the script (see Kulfy's comment on the answer).

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
#!/bin/bash

for I in {1..5) do echo $I done
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash

for I in {1..5}; do echo $I; done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
for I in {1..5}
  do
    echo $I
  done
```

Placing either of the above in a new file, giving it execution permissions and executing it with the command `$ bash *filename*` output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I'm not sure why it's printing `{1..5}` for you because the code you posted gives me a syntax error, but fixing the typo and adding the semicolons made it execute correctly on my installation.

The only way I was able to make it output `{1..5}` was by modifying the code to encapsulate the arguments in quotations so it would be interpreted as a string as so:

```
#!/bin/bash
for I in "{1..5}"
  do
    echo $I
  done
```

If you could provide the exact contents of your file, I could attempt to help you further.

Alternatively, if you're executing via `sh *filename*` you're essentially executing `dash *filename*` which I don't believe supports that notation.

Comment: Are you getting `{1..5}` as the output? Are you running the script like `sh sciptName.sh`?

Comment: @Kulfy I think that Kaleb Burklow is not getting the output `{1..5}`, but referring to OP's statement that they got that output. But my suspicion is that OP made the typo `{1..5)` *only in the question* and the real answer is somewhere in your comment, since they can't have got `{1..5}` with the code they wrote, but they could have got it the way you suggested.

Comment: @Kulfy I've clarified my answer to state my output and method of execution, along with a possible cause of OPs output.

Comment: nice improvement - quoting is another possible explanation which seems even more likely